# Power series representation of $f(x) = \frac{1}{x+2}$

Tags: power-series

In attempting to find the power series representation of $f(x)$, using the fact:

$$\frac{1}{1 - t} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{t^n}$$

I simply set $t = -x - 1$, which when substituting into the above formula gives $f(x)$.  Therefore, I presumed that the power series representation of $f(x)$ is $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{(-x - 1)^n} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{(-1)^n(x + 1)^n}$.

But apparently this is wrong, and have seen a more complicated derivation, that also seems correct, that gives $\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}{\frac{(-1)^n}{2^{n+1}}x^n}$

Can anyone provide any insight into why my more simplistic derivation is wrong?

**EDIT:** To clarify, I would like to point that I understand that the second derivation is correct and I understand how it is derived.  What I want to know is why my derivation is wrong.

Comment: As stated, your problem doesn't make sense. You're after the power series representation of $f$ *centered at which point*?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I'm sorry, I don't understand what you mean?

Comment: A power series is a series of the type $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(x-a)^n$. What is your $a$?

Comment: What makes you think that your result is wrong? Your result yields a power series representation, but not centered a 0, but centered at $-1$ $(x+1=x-(-1))$.

Comment: I'm completely confused, the question is simply 'Find the power series representation for $\frac{1}{x+2}$'.  Maybe I'm not understanding the idea properly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your derivation is **not** wrong.

It simply gives the power series developed *about a different point*. The series

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{2^{n+1}} x^n$$

is developed about the point $x = 0$, while

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n (x + 1)^n$$

is developed about the point $x = -1$. Typically, one "likes" to have a series expansion of the first type since simple powers are easier to deal with than powers involving an addition, but there is no *need* for the first kind of expansion and moreover, they may not exist in many cases due to singular behavior at the origin, e.g. the function $x \mapsto \frac{1}{x}$ directly, or $\log$. If you were specifically asked for the series to be *developed at $x = 0$* then the answer would be wrong. If no development point is advanced, and yet this is considered wrong, then the problem wasn't stated well to begin with.

ADD: from the comments, the meaning of "development point" is because the general power series has the form

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n (x - c)^n$$

The point "$c$" is called the "center". The reason for calling it such is two-fold: one reason is because such series, when they converge, do so within a circle (most literally in the complex plane, but on the real numbers, an interval constitutes a 1-d "circle") about this point. Another reason is that this point is the one of maximum rate of convergence (namely, infinitely fast, since at $x = 0$ it "instantly" converges to the value of $a_0$).

Comment: It seems this book has let me down in terms of giving a proper understanding.  I didn't know that functions had multiple power series representations.  So what is the meaning behind 'developed' or 'centred'? In other words, what is the importance or usefulness in deciding/choosing this value?

Comment: @esotechnica May I ask which book it is?

Comment: Stewart's Calculus 8th Ed - I realise it's not the most rigorous of books, but it's what I've got.  It's Example 11.9.2

Answer (score 4):

The function doesn't have a unique series representation; you found the one centered at $-1$ and the formula is correct.

If you were asked for the representation around $0$, then you gave the wrong answer. The phrase “power series” without qualifications usually means a series of the form
$$
\sum_{n}a_nx^n
$$
which yours isn't.

Comment: OK, so a power series without qualification means 'power series centred at zero'?

Comment: @esotechnica I'd say so, but it's a convention that you should check in your textbook.

Answer (score 1):

There could be three cases and one can use infinite geometric series: $(1+z)^{-1}=1-z+z^2-z^3+\dots+(-z)^k+\cdots,$ if $|z|<1.$

1. When $-2<x<2$, $$f(x) =\frac{1}{2} \left(1+\frac{x}{2}\right)^{-1}=
   =\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-x)^k}{2^{k+1}};$$
2. When $x<-2$ or $x>2$: $$f(x)=\frac{1}{x} \left(1+\frac{2}{x}\right)^{-1}= \sum_{0}^{\infty} \frac{(-2)^k}{x^{n+1}};$$
3. When $a<x<b$ (e.g., when $a=2$, and $b=3$) $$ f(x)=\frac{1}{4+y}=\frac{1}{4} \left(1+\frac{y}{4} \right)^{-1} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-y)^k}{4^{k+1}},~ y=(x-2).$$